# Downloding input stream as a file(attachment)

Tags: java, servlets, download

I have data that is coming into an input stream. I have a servlet where i get the data. I want to download the received data as a file.
This is the code i have come up with so far, but with no success. Any help will be great! Thanks!

```
final InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(fetchFile.getObjectContent());
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
byte[] outputByte = new byte[bytes.length];
while(in.read(outputByte, 0, bytes.length) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, bytes.length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Any errors in particular that you face?

Comment: No errors, no Exceptions, but doesnt show anything.